# Show data charged from asyncronous callback JS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got a function that accesses to a database on firebase and I get the data doing this:

```
private chargeData() {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + this.auth.uid);
    ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('Charge data error, ', error.code);
    });
  }
```

I'm using ionic 3 so I want to keep all that I received on a local variable to show it on the HTML view but I don't know how. I try to initialize a variable like `this.userData = snapshot.val();` but an error occurred "This is null".

Comment: Use arrow function as callback

Answer (score -1):

Use Angular data-binding

```
private theData;

private chargeData() {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + this.auth.uid);
    ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      this.theData = snapshot.val();
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('Charge data error, ', error.code);
    });
  }
```

in HTML:

```
<div class="fancy"> {{ theData }} </div>
```

further details:

- https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data
- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax